# How to revert/downgrade Windows Phone 8.1 app to C#5, I have accidentally upgraded to C#6

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

How to revert Windows Phone 8.1 app to C#5, I have accidentally upgraded to C#6 and the project is not compiling anymore.  Does anyone know how to revert to C#5? Thanks.

Long story: I wanted to try out a new feature (the null propagation in C#6 but this broke everything ^^)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087830/downgrade-net-4-5-application-to-4-0 Check this link because I think you have to right all your code again

Comment: I am sure that there is a targetFramework somewhere but i just cant seem to find it!

Comment: if you need targetFramework just rightclick on solution and click property and it is application tab. Cheers :)

Comment: If I could I would have done it already =) : http://i.imgur.com/h7wR9Rx.png   I cant seem to be able to change the traget framework from within Visual Studio